# vba delete rows of each sheets under multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I please need your help with a code, that from my side I Think is very complicated.

So the idea is :

> For sheet 1, if cell in column A <> ws.name then
>
> if cells in column F =55 and cells in column G = any number from 1 to
> 12 then do nothing
>
> if cells in column F = any number from 1 to 12 and cells in column G
> =55 then do nothing
>
> else delete all other rows
>
> PS: I have around 20000 rows
>
> Also for Sheet 2, if cell in column A <> ws.name then
>
> if cells in column F =51 or = 53 and cells in column G = 55 then do
> nothing
>
> if cells in column F = 55 and cells in column G =51 or =53 then do
> nothing
>
> else delete all other rows

And so on, for each sheet I'll be having different number conditions in columns F & G.

I really hope you can help, I've been struggling with this for a while

Here's the code I tried of exemple in one sheet

```
Sub loopanddelete()

Dim i As Long, fVal, gVal
Dim ws As Worksheet, rngDel As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False

Set ws = Sheets("209990")

For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then
        fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And (gVal >= 1 And gVal <= 12)) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal >= 1 And fVal <= 12)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
   End If

   If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
       fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
       gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

       If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And ((gVal >= 1 And gVal <= 12) Or gVal = 55)) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And ((fVal >= 1 And fVal <= 12) Or fVal = 55)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
       End If
  End If
   
Next i
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows

  Set ws = Sheets("209991")

  For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then
        fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And (gVal= 51 Or gVal=53)) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =51 Or fVal =53)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
   End If

 If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
       fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
       gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And ((gVal= 51 Or gVal=53)or gVal=55)) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =51 Or fVal =53)or fVal=55) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
       End If
  End If
   
Next i
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows

Set ws = Sheets("209992")

For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then
        fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And (gVal= 50 Or gVal=52)) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =50 Or fVal =52)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
   End If

If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
       fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
       gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And ((gVal= 50 Or gVal=52)or gVal=55)) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =50 Or fVal =52)or fVal=55) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
       End If
  End If
Next i
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows


Set ws = Sheets("209995")

For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then
        fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And gVal= 45) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =45)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
   End If

 If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
       fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
       gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And (gVal= 45 or gVal=55)) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =45 or fVal=55)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
       End If
  End If
Next i
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows

Set ws = Sheets("209997")

For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then
        fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And gVal= 57) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =57)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
   End If

If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
       fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
       gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And (gVal= 47 or gVal=55)) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =47 or fVal=55)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
       End If
  End If
Next i
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows

Set ws = Sheets("209998")

For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then
        fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And gVal= 48) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =48)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
   End If

If ws.Cells(i, 1) = ws.Name Then
       fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
       gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

        If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
            If Not (fVal = 55 And (gVal= 48 or gVal=55)) And _
               Not (gVal = 55 And (fVal =48 or fVal=55)) Then
                BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
            End If
       End If
  End If
Next i
If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows
End Sub

Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
If rngTot Is Nothing Then
    Set rngTot = rngAdd
Else
    Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you set `ws` sheet? What are you expecting from `ws.Range("A20000:G20000").End(xlUp).Row`? `"1" <= Cells(i, 7).Value >= "12"` is wrong in VBA. You must set each condition in a separate statement. `Cells(i, 7).Value <= 1` and  `Cells(i, 7).Value >= 12`. Then, eliminate the double quotes, which converts in a string from the value to be compared.

Comment: You always must use the optimization part **only after the code has been tested and it works as you need**! I mean, the lines `DisplayAlerts`, `ScreenUpdating` etc.

Comment: Also, notice that `Range("A20000:G20000")` is a single row. I think you mean `Range("A2:G20000") maybe?`

Comment: @FaneDuru, thank you for your feedback. ws sheet is each sheet I want it to change and for 'ws.Range("A20000:G20000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1', is like i'm telling to go through each line from the row 20000 to the top. I'm deleting the optimization part and correcting the code to see if it will work.

Comment: You want that, but I am afraid that `ws.Range("A20000:G20000").End(xlUp).Row` returns the last cell in column A:A. Try `Debug.Print ws.Range("A20000:G20000").End(xlUp).Row:Stop`. What does it return in Immediate window? I would suggest to use `For i = 20000 To 2 Step -1` and fully qualify the cells. I mean to use `ws.Cells(i, 1)`, `ws.Cells(i, 6)` and so on. Otherwise your code works on the active sheet all the time. And try better understanding what I tried clarifying in my previous comment, please.

Comment: Do not place code lines in comment. Please, edit your question and update the code there. We cannot understand what you want saying. On which line does the error appear?

Comment: I asked you **Where did you set `ws` sheet?** as the first sentence in my initial comment... Do you understand what this means?

Comment: I just added an answer with code.

Comment: Didn't I already set the ws sheet when i selected the sheet 209990 ?

Comment: You only selected it, there! Which, anyhow is not necessary... You must use 'Set ws = Worksheets("209990")`...

Comment: @faneDuru, I'm sorry but i don't think you read my initial question right and what i'm lokking for.  
The code I wrote is only a part of it, just to try to run it as an exemple for one sheet. I can't set ws as one sheet and then change it for each sheet. Thank you. 
and sorry for the answer as I'm new here. I don't know how the code passed that line, but I had the error right after it.
Thank you.

Comment: Which initial question? Was there another one? But did you read my first comment? Anyhow, not seeing your code I cannot help. And now I am driving...

Comment: Err, you know you can use Autofilter to achieve what you want? Much faster than looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub ProcessSheets()

    RemoveRowsByValue Sheets("209990"), 55, 12
    RemoveRowsByValue Sheets("209991"), 44, 9
    RemoveRowsByValue Sheets("209992"), 33, 15

End Sub


Sub RemoveRowsByValue(ws As Worksheet, valOne, valTwo)

    Dim i As Long, fVal, gVal, s
    Dim rngDel As Range 'this range holds the rows to be deleted
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'not sure if you really need this...
    
    For i = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 'loop backwards
        If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Name Then   'Col A check
            fVal = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value   'Col F value
            gVal = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value   'Col G value
            If IsNumeric(fVal) And IsNumeric(gVal) Then
                If Not (fVal = valOne And (gVal >= 1 And gVal <= valTwo)) And _
                   Not (gVal = valOne And (fVal >= 1 And fVal <= valTwo)) Then
                    BuildRange rngDel, ws.Cells(i, 1)
                End If
            End If
       End If
    Next i
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete any flagged rows
End Sub

'utility sub to build a range piece-by-piece
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then   'check if we've already begun this range
        Set rngTot = rngAdd     '...if not just make the direct assignment
    Else
        'rngTot already has content, so add `rngAdd` using Union
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Tim Williams, Thanks a lot, that's amazing, it works. But I really would like to understand better the code you wrote. Specially the built range part, in order to be able to use it and modify it if i get the chance any other time.  Also, could you please advise on how can I set the sheet to change each time ? should I identify mutliple ws (1 to 10 ) as worksheets ? for exemple `ws(1)=Sheets("209990")` ; `ws(2)=Sheets("209991")` etc .. 
Thanks again

Comment: Added some comments and a loop for multiple sheets.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanations. 
But actually, each sheet will have different number conditions, so I don't think the array  is the right function to use ?Maybe the select function, select each sheet before the changes to make ? Thanks

Comment: Is it only the 12 and 55 which vary between sheets?

Comment: Yes,  each sheet will have other numbers in fval and gval

Comment: See above - you can create parameters for the worksheet and the two values, and call the sub with different arguments for each sheet.

Comment: Actually, I won't work as sometimes it will be OR instead of And  .. and will have different numbers.. I edited my question with the code including all the details of what I need, but of course I can't set the sheet each time to another one.

Comment: Since I answered your original question it might be best to post a new question with your "expanded" requirements, and mark this one as closed.

Comment: Sorry I'm just new here, i don't know how it works.. but sure I'll do so. Thanks

Comment: Question posted .. Thanks